# My Service Worker [angular] is blocking requests to Facebook Pixel

Tags: angular, service-worker

I need to install a Facebook Pixel in my Angular application, but the service worker blocks it.

It only works when I forcefully reload the page.

Any tips?

Error:
GET https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

If I disable the Service Worker, everything works.

Service Worker:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "!/favicon.ico",
          "!/index.html",
          "!/manifest.webmanifest",
          "!/*.css",
          "!/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": ["/**"],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 200,
      "maxAge": "3d",
      "timeout": "15s"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a add blocker that blocks it ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes, I'm sure. If I disable the Service Worker, everything works